# How are people handling this caching use case?

Tags: performance, http, caching

I have a controller action that is very slow, so I've decided to add caching to it. The way caching is typically used in Rails is something like this:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("some_key") {
   # expensive operation here, if some_key is not already in the cache store
}
```

So, if `some_key` exists in the cache, it's value is being read, and the expensive operation is not executed. The expensive operation would be executed if I delete the key, or, in case it's auto expiring ( based on some database field, or whatever ). Thus, whenever a client would call that controller action, and the cache was just expired, he would have to wait a long time for a response.

To work against this, I've decided to do the invalidation in a separate task, and to replace the cache content ( whenever the key is static ) so that there would be no requests that would take a long time ( I can accept a few seconds of possible stale data responses being sent to the client ). In theory, it seems like a good approach to having good performance. I'd like to knowm are other people using similar techniques in production? Any drawbacks/fatal flaw I'm not seeing to doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [fresh_when(record_or_options, additional_options = {})](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/fresh_when)

Sets the etag, last_modified, or both on the response and renders a 304 Not Modified response if the request is already fresh.

2. Use [expires_in(seconds, options = {})](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/expires_in)

Sets a HTTP 1.1 Cache-Control header. Defaults to issuing a private instruction, so that intermediate caches must not cache the response.

3. Use [expires_now()](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/ConditionalGet/expires_now)

Sets a HTTP 1.1 Cache-Control header of no-cache so no caching should occur by the browser or intermediate caches (like caching proxy servers).

You should use different types of caching based on data type and data change frequency.

1. [Time-based cache headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching-ruby-rails#time-based-cache-headers)
2. [Conditional cache headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching-ruby-rails#conditional-cache-headers)
3. [Non-cacheable content](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching-ruby-rails#non-cacheable-content)

Also see Advanced Caching: Caching Strategies
[Part 1](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_1-caching_strategies/)
[Part 2](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_2-using_strategies/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a very good approach. Except of course for the first hit scenario. Also preemptively refeshing (nearly) expired cache items might create a big memory usage, but I'm guessing you already thought of that and considered it managable, if so then in that case..what's stopping you from caching all the possible key values in some sort of bulk action when the application start? it would eliminate the first hit problem as well.